# Updating progress bar in Django with values from python file without Celery and Ajax

Tags: python, django, progress-bar

I am very new to Django. I am trying to create a progress bar in index.html file, which will check for the completion of a particular task in python file and send the status continously (through render) to index.html file. The html file will have progress bar which will continuously monitor the progress and update it on the fly. I have seen posts about progress bar with celery , but it is not supported in windows.
Please excuse me for mistakes since it is my first post here.

Comment: use `AJAX`  in `JavaScript` (`XMLHttpRequest`) or in `jQuery` (`$.ajax()`)

Comment: Can you please elaborate little more @furas

Comment: browser can get new data from server when it (re)loads page (it sends requests for new or the same URL and it reloads full page) or when `JavaScript` uses `AJAX` to ask for new data from URL (without reloading page). To use `AJAX` you can use pure JavaScript with [XMLHttpRequest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/XMLHttpRequest) or simpler use JavaScript's library like `jQuery` which has method [jquery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). You can find many examples how to use `jQuery.ajax()` - but all this need to learn `JavaScript`. You can't do this without JavaScript.

Comment: Okay thanks for the suggestion. I wanted without browser refresh, so I will try to learn JavaScript and then use AJAX

Comment: I have only [example for Flask](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/flask/ajax-settimeout-refresh-periodically/main.py) - it uses JavaScript `settimeout` to run periodically jQuery `$.get()` to get current time from server.

Comment: Thanks for that...i will try to follow it and implement for Django.